# Why is titleTextStyle not working with the title option in Google Charts?

Tags: php, html, charts, google-visualization

I'm creating a simple bar chart using Google Charts with the data fetched from Mysql Database. The chart is displayed properly but I'm unable to format the title of the graph. I have referred to many sites and I'm sure the syntax for 'titleTextStyle' is fine. But the title does not change with the options at all. Can somebody tell me where the problem lies ? 
I have attached my full code below. 
Thanks in advance.

```
<?php 

    include("toconnect.php");
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT Product_name,COUNT(*)  FROM Items_Sold GROUP BY Product_name");

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Product Name', 'Frequency'],
          <?php 
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                            echo "['".$row["Product_name"]."','".$row["COUNT(*)"]."'],";
                    }
            }
          ?>
        ]);

        var options = {
          chart: {
            title: "Frequently Bought items",titleTextStyle:{ color: '#007DB0',fontName: "Times",fontSize: 60,bold: true},
        }
        };
        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));

        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="columnchart_material" style="width: 800px; height: 500px;display:inline-block;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `options` variable needs the `chart` object removed - so `var options={title:'',titleTextStyle:{}};`

Comment: @RamRaider Thanks a lot ! It worked !

Comment: alternatively you can move the `titleTextStyle` object literal outside of the `chart` object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are working with a *material* chart...

```
google.charts.Bar
```

the list of features not working in *Material* charts can be found here...

[Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity #2143](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

which includes...

`titleTextStyle`

---

try working with a *classic* chart instead...

```
google.visualization.ColumnChart
```

with option...

`theme: 'material'`